# ARM64/ARM32 difference branch

Tags: arm, branch, arm64

If in ARM32 branch have these opcode: EAFF FFFE, then what would this opcode be in ARM64?

Example:

ARM32:

```
0000: b $+0
```

ARM64:

```
0000: b $+0
```

Comment: what part of the arm documentation did you not understand?

Comment: @dwelch I did not understand what part of this code EAFFFFFE is address and how long it be in ARM64

Comment: @dwelch or please say me, how i can create ARM64 binary with this instructions? Google could not help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution from DEFCON: 0x00000014